# Not Able To Access Records In Role Hierarchy

Tags: administration, security, role-hierarchy

I am a salesforce developer but new to admin. Tring to understand security settings using role hierarchy and having an issue or confusion here. I'll try to explain this below.

I have two roles in the role hierarchy assigned to two users.

Ideally, the records of user down in the hierarchy should be accessed by the upper role assigned user but I am not able to see those records in the upper role user.

The OWD is set to private and the object on which I am checking is contact object so by default Grant Access Using Hierarchies is on.
I am not getting the issue here. Please tell me where I am wrong or missing something.

Answer (score -1):

In salesforce, the contacts with no accounts can't be accessed to other than owner and system administrator.
Here no heirarchy roles or sharing rules work.

It was salesforce default functionality.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because I think it completely misses the mark. There is no indication in the question about Contacts. While Contacts _could_ be involved, this strikes me as an issue about roles/sharing in general.